# Java regular expression for checking inputed names

Tags: java, regex

I know regular expressions aren't necessarily the best tool for the job, but I was wondering whether this would be possible with Java regexen:

Let's say I have a data set with names separated by line breaks like so:

```
John Doe  
Jane Roe  
Richard Miles
```

(there are naturally a *lot* more names in the actual system)

I'll be reading in data where I'll get both the first and the last name separately, but they won't necessarily be in the same order.

Now, the question is, is there any way to construct a regex for, say, Richard Miles that would match both "Miles Richard" and "Richard Miles"? I know there are plenty of other ways to do this, but I'm specifically looking for a regex-based solution (not because it's necessarily practical, but I'd find it interesting)

**Edit for clarification**: what I mean is that I need a regex for, say, "Richard Miles" that will match on both "Richard Miles" and "Miles Richard", and preferably not just `(Richard Miles|Miles Richard)` because where's the fun in that?

This is in no way supposed to be practical, I'm merely interested whether regexen can do something like this.

Comment: So you are looking for a regex that matches all characters up to a space and then the rest of the characters up to a new line. Is that correct?

Comment: No, regexes make no fun of that - `(Richard Miles|Miles Richard)` *is* the (one and only) solution

Answer (score 2):

Does it need to be complex and clever?  I mean this would work.

```
\b(Miles Richard|Richard Miles)\b
```

Comment: Oh yes, that'll absolutely work. I'm really not after something that works, but something that's exceedingly clever. I'd just like to know whether regexen can do something like this

Comment: I thought you might be, just wasn't sure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take a look at this: -

```
^(\\w+)\\s(\\w+)$
```

It will match a word at the beginning`(^\\w+)`, followed by a space `(\\s)`, followed by another word at the end`(\\w+$)`

Are you looking for this only?

Comment: I clarified my question a bit.

Comment: @tomek You want to match both of them at the same time? In one line back to back?

Comment: @tomek Take look at my edited pattern.. Are you looking for this?

Comment: I clarified my question a bit more. I'm just looking for a needlessly clever (and frankly quite stupid) way to match names so that when given a regex for "Richard Miles", the regex would match both "Miles Richard" and "Richard Miles" *without* being simply (Richard Miles|Miles Richard)

Think of it like code golf, but with regexen.

Comment: @tomek Have you even tried that regex with both of them. It would match any two words separated by a space. Try it out. And then if it doesn't matches then you can ask me again. I'll try with some other regex.